# Powershell and network paths

Tags: powershell

I am calling one of my scripts from a network path. Script basically only calls another program and passes to it the current directory as an argument.

When I pass $PWD as an argument, the path that my program sees is "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\my_server\public", and it of course fails because it expects standard UNC path.

My ad hoc solution was to simply do `.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")` and it worked, but I wonder what is the real way to convert path from this "powershell" format to the standard UNC.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `$pwd.ProviderPath` instead.

```
PS Home:\> cd \\localhost\h$
PS FileSystem::\\localhost\h$> $pwd|fl -force *


Drive        :
Provider     : FileSystem
ProviderPath : \\localhost\h$
Path         : FileSystem::\\localhost\h$
```

Besides, there is a `-replace` operator, you don't necessarily need that method call.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Btw, this | fl -force * trick will be very handy in the future. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: It's a quick way of seeing all properties an object has (instead of only those that are *by default* displayed). If you just look at `$pwd` it will only show you `Path`, not the others. Another useful thing is `Get-Member` or `gm`, but that doesn't show the values, so if I'm looking for property values I expect to be there (as in this case) I usually use `Format-List` :-)